# Trying to update Airflow Variable within python operator in GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am trying to update the airflow variable within a python operator. Outside the operator, I can update, but within operator, getting some error

```
Variable.update('inv_test_var', '2023-06-28 04:12:00') # it works
def py_function():

  print("**************************************************")
  #new_var = Variable.get('inv_test_var')
  Variable.update('inv_test_var','2023-06-28 04:20:00') # not worked
  print("**************************************************")
```

within a dag, I have called this function py_function

ERROR - Google Cloud API Call Error (NotFound): Secret ID inv_test_var not found.

Not sure, why in operator, its not getting updated. Can anyone please let me know?

Comment: from the error looks like it looking for a variable in the secret backend and it variable does not exist in secret backend. have you configured the google secret backend?

Comment: I am not sure on that Pankaj.. But my question is, Is it possible to access the airflow variable within Operators in Airflow. If yes, how do we can achieve it? or is it mandated to configure google secret backend to access the Airflow variable.. please let me know

Comment: its working.. I haven't made any changes.. it seems like Airflow used to look for secret first, whenever we are using Variable.get / Variable.update in operator.. But subsequently the airflow variable is getting updated.. but we used to get that error in the logs.. this mentioned code will work...

Comment: yes, it works with both `Variable.set(...)` as well as `Variable.update(...)`

Comment: > is it mandated to configure google secret backend to access the Airflow variable                                                                                                                                     No, but from the error log looks like we have google secret backed so I thought maybe you are getting error because of that

Comment: No Problem, thanks Pankaj for jumping in..

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cloud API Call Error (NotFound): Secret ID inv_test_var not found](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fd116cc1964c49e21aaac6062fff596764833c59/airflow/providers/google/cloud/_internal_client/secret_manager_client.py#L76) is a log statement in Google secret backend code in the Airflow codebase.

Otherwise both

`Variable.set(key="some_key", value="some_value")` as well as `Variable.update(key="some_key", value="some_value)` work inside operator.